# Error with Typescript Pact.io test: PopsicleError: Unable to connect to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, pact

**Expected:** Running `npm run pactTest` should generate a pact file (JSON).

**Results:** I get an `Unable to connect` error.

[Pact.io JavaScript implementation guide.](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/javascript)

[Pact.io Typescript test example.](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/examples/typescript/test/get-dog.spec.ts)

Appreciate any thoughts or ideas as to what I'm doing wrong :)

---

**The Error**

> FAIL  src/services/api/TotalPayout.test.pact.ts
>     The API
>       getUsersTotalPayout
>         ✕ Should call getUsersTotalPayout and return an object with the total_payout (45ms)
>
> ● The API › getUsersTotalPayout › Should call getUsersTotalPayout and return an object with the total_payout
>
> PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:12345/interactions"
>       Caused by: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:12345
>
> ```
>  at Request.Object.<anonymous>.Request.error (node_modules/popsicle/src/request.ts:91:12)
>   at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/popsicle/src/index.ts:218:31)
> ```

**package.json script:**

```
"pactTest": "export NODE_ENV=pactTest && jest --testRegex \"/*(.test.pact.ts)\" --runInBand --setupFiles ./pactSetup.ts --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile ./pactTestWrapper.ts",
```

**My src/pactSetup.ts file**

```
// @ts-ignore
import path from 'path';
import { Pact } from '@pact-foundation/pact/pact';
​
// @ts-ignore
global.provider = new Pact({
  port: 1234,
  log: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'logs', 'mockserver-integration.log'),
  dir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'pacts'),
  spec: 2,
  cors: true,
  pactfileWriteMode: 'update',
  consumer: 'Exchange',
  provider: 'LP Service'
});
```

**My src/pactTestWrapper.ts**

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000; // This is to give the pact mock server time to start
​
// @ts-ignore
beforeAll(() => provider.setup()); // Create mock provider
// @ts-ignore
afterEach(() => provider.verify()); // Ensure the mock provider verifies expected interactions for each test
// @ts-ignore
afterAll(() => provider.finalize()); // Tear down the mock and write the pact
```

**The test: src/services/api/TotalPayout.test.pact.ts**

```
// @ts-ignore
import path from 'path';
import { Pact } from '@pact-foundation/pact';
import { getTotalPayout } from './apiPayout';

const port = 12345;
const endpoint = '/frontoffice/api/get-total-payout';

const EXPECTED_BODY = {
  total_payout: 100.21,
};

const userId = 'foo';

const provider = new Pact({
  port,
  log: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'logs', 'mockserver-integration.log'),
  dir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'pacts'),
  spec: 2,
  consumer: 'Exchange',
  provider: 'LP Service',
  pactfileWriteMode: 'merge'
});
​​
describe('The API', () => {
  // Copy this block once per interaction under test
  describe('getUsersTotalPayout', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const interaction = {
        uponReceiving: 'a GET request with a user id',
        withRequest: {
          method: 'GET',
          path: endpoint,
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
          },
        },
        willRespondWith: {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: EXPECTED_BODY
        },
      };

      // @ts-ignore
      return provider.addInteraction(interaction);
    });
​
    // add expectations
    it('Should call getUsersTotalPayout and return an object with the total_payout', done => {
      getTotalPayout(userId)
        .then((response: any) => {
          expect(response).toEqual(EXPECTED_BODY);
        })
        .then(done);
    });
  });
});
```

**The api service file apiPayout.ts**

```
// @ts-ignore
import axios, * as others from 'axios';

const endpoint = '/frontoffice/api/';

export const getTotalPayout = async (userId: string) => {
  const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}get-total-payout`, { params: userId });
  return response.data;
};
```

**From the mockserver-integration.log**

```
I, [2018-09-19T11:07:41.259437 #79922]  INFO -- : Verifying - interactions matched
I, [2018-09-19T11:07:41.264440 #79922]  INFO -- : Cleared interactions
```

**From the debug-log**

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error react-redux-starter-kit@1.0.0 pactTest: `export NODE_ENV=pactTest && jest --testRegex "/*(.test.pact.ts)" --runInBand --setupFiles ./pactSetup.ts --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile ./pactTestWrapper.ts`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-redux-starter-kit@1.0.0 pactTest script.
```

### Update

After commenting out the provider setup logic in the test.pact file and re-running `npm run pactTest` I get the following:

> console.error node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact/pact.js:110
>       Pact verification failed!
>
> console.error node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact/pact.js:111
>       Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.
>
> Missing requests:
>           GET /frontoffice/api/liquidity-pool/get-total-payout
>
> See /Users/leongaban/projects/trade.io/tradeio-front/logs/mockserver-integration.log for details.

[image]

**And my updated mockserver-intergration.log**

```
I, [2018-09-19T14:12:19.128823 #82330]  INFO -- : Registered expected interaction GET /frontoffice/api/liquidity-pool/get-total-payout
D, [2018-09-19T14:12:19.129127 #82330] DEBUG -- : {
  "description": "a GET request with a user id",
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/frontoffice/api/liquidity-pool/get-total-payout",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
      "total_payout": 100.21
    }
  }
}
W, [2018-09-19T14:12:19.139198 #82330]  WARN -- : Verifying - actual interactions do not match expected interactions. 
Missing requests:
    GET /frontoffice/api/liquidity-pool/get-total-payout


W, [2018-09-19T14:12:19.139254 #82330]  WARN -- : Missing requests:
    GET /frontoffice/api/liquidity-pool/get-total-payout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues I can point out:

- You seem to be declaring and spinning a pact mock server twice: in the `src/pactSetup.ts` file and also in `TotalPayout.test.pact.ts` which I'm not sure it's what you intended to do. You probably want to avoid declaring the provider in the TotalPayout test, and instead you already have the `provider` object on the global scope as part of the test framework setup files.
- In the code `apiPayout.ts` you are referring to the endpoint URL, but to which port is it sending the request? This API call should be ultimately caught by the pact mock provider that you are spinning up. If you call to a different port than what the mock provider is listening on you'll never hit it.
- A small nitpick: `/frontoffice/api/get-total-payout` is not a RESTful. You want to avoid including verbs such as "get" in your API and use the proper HTTP method for that (GET).

Comment: Hey thanks, ok I'm getting somewhere now, I'll update my answer with the new errors and logs.

Comment: Also noted about the RESTful endpoint hehe, it doesn't exist yet and I just wrote something random, it will defs be named something like `/payouts`. Actually will post a new question related to the new errors. Thanks!

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Comment: why was this accepted as the answer?  i see nothing in it that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that was your problem, but I had the order of writePact and finalize wrong. I had:

```
afterAll(async () => {
  await provider.finalize()
  await provider.writePact()
})
```

instead of the correct order:

```
afterAll(async () => {
  await provider.writePact()
  await provider.finalize()
})
```